# How to display an alert/confirmation message in Django views function?

Tags: python, django

I have written a Django view function to delete a user from AWS DynamoDB. Below is my views python function snippet :

```
def deluser(request):
   db=boto3.client('dynamodb', region_name='us-west-2')
   acc=request.GET.get('acc')
   uid=request.GET.get('uid')
   aname=request.GET.get('aname')
   db.delete_item(
      TableName='User-Account',
         Key={
             'UserId': {'S': uid},
             'AccountNum': {'S': acc}
              }
                 )
   messages.add_message(request, messages.INFO, 'User '+uid+' successfully 
    removed from '+acc+' : '+aname)


   return useracc(request)
```

I am deleting a userid based on account number in a DynamoDB table. I have used Django message to display that the user has been removed. However, I would like to include a confirmation message/ alert asking like "Do you really want to remove/delete the user ?" before deleting it. If the user clicks on Yes only then the user will be deleted otherwise No. How can I do this ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Usually it is a frontend-only confirmation. So, wherever your submit button is, you can add an alert on clicking it and then depending on the confirmation, process the ordinary form submit.

Answer (score 0):

Use javascript to display a confirmation dialog:

```
confirm('Do you really want to remove/delete the user ?')
```

If the user id is used in other tables as a foreign key, it would be better to 'deactivate' the user instead of deleting the user.